# Invalid write of size 8 during pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, valgrind

I've got simple TCP server app. It consists of main function, TCP thread function and thread timer (TCP thread ends after 45 secs). Problem is in creation of threads. Server runs for a while and then suddenly crashes. This is the way I create threads (in while cycle):

```
for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
    freethreads[i] = i;

clients++;
pthread_mutex_lock(&clientMtx);
tmp.sockfd = new_sockfd;
tmp.threadid = NTHREADS - clients;

pthread_create(&threadid[freethreads[NTHREADS - clients]], &attr, &tcp_main, &tmp);
sleep(0);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientMtx);
```

and here are logs from valgrind and helgrind at pastebin:
[valgrind](http://pastebin.com/2aALxQYu)
[helgrind](http://pastebin.com/mDcEQpwJ)
I got no idea, what could this part mean:

```
==3405== Invalid write of size 8
==3405==    at 0x4E3A52F: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:563)
==3405==    by 0x4027DF: main (robot4.c:489)
==3405==  Address 0x8872e9c0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Thanks a lot for every advice.

EDIT:
threadid and freethreads part:

```
pthread_t threadid[NTHREADS]; 
int freethreads[NTHREADS];
for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
freethreads[i] = i;
```

Comment: Show your definition and initialization for `threadid`.

Comment: Even with the mutex and the `sleep` call that way of passing the arguments to the thread not guaranteed to be safe. Instead I recommend you allocate the structure used for `tmp` dynamically on the heap for every thread. Once the threads have saved the data from the structure they can then free it.

Comment: Did you try seeing the core dump with GDB? Does it offer a clue for the crash?

Comment: Yes, my friend found out that mistake according to @JoachimPileborg 's post. Crash was made by my mistake in different function (timeout func), which manipulated with clients variable.
Don't you know, is it possible to delete whole question? I think, it will be useless for people, because of that mistake in different part of code...

Answer (score 2):

Going only by the code you shown us in the question, it could be that `clients` is increased to become larger than `NTHREADS`, leading to you having a negative index for the `freethreads` array.

Indexing out of bounds of an array, in either direction, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to check that `clients` never becomes larger than `NTHREADS`, and of course also decrease it when clients disconnect (while taking care that it never goes below zero).

Comment: I'm decreasing clients everytime client disconnects and I'm checking that variable in while loop this way: `pthread_mutex_lock(&clientMtx); if (clients == NTHREADS) pthread_cond_wait(&clientCond, &clientMtx)  pthread_mutex_unlock(&clientMtx);`  
sorry for formating, I can't figure out, how to do it...